# Eclipse Node.getTextContent() in Java 1.6.0_20

Tags: java, xml, eclipse, dom

I am facing trouble with Node.getTextContent() of org.w3c.dom. I have following code block:

```
String name = document.getElementsByTagName("name").item(0).getTextContent();
```

And eclipse giving me `The method getTextContent() is undefined for the type Node`. What is the problem I don't understand.

Thanks and regards.

---

Edit:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>FBApp</groupId>
    <artifactId>FBApp</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>war</packaging>

    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>java.net.maven1</id>
            <name>java.net</name>
            <url>http://download.java.net/maven/1</url>
        </repository>
        <repository>
            <id>maven2-repository.java.net</id>
            <name>Java.net Repository for Maven</name>
            <url>http://download.java.net/maven/2/</url>
        </repository>
    </repositories>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.faces</groupId>
            <artifactId>jsf-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.2</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.faces</groupId>
            <artifactId>jsf-impl</artifactId>
            <version>1.2</version>
            <type>jar</type>
            <classifier>NIGHTLY_20060227</classifier>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>       
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-beanutils</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-beanutils</artifactId>
            <version>1.7.0</version>
            <type>jar</type>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-beanutils</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-beanutils-bean-collections</artifactId>
            <version>1.7.0</version>
            <type>jar</type>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-beanutils</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-beanutils-core</artifactId>
            <version>1.7.0</version>
            <type>jar</type>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-codec</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-codec</artifactId>
            <version>1.3</version>
            <type>jar</type>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-collections</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-collections</artifactId>
            <version>3.1</version>
            <type>jar</type>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-digester</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-digester</artifactId>
            <version>1.7</version>
            <type>jar</type>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-el</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-el</artifactId>
            <version>1.0</version>
            <type>jar</type>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-fileupload</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-fileupload</artifactId>
            <version>1.0</version>
            <type>jar</type>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-lang</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-lang</artifactId>
            <version>2.2</version>
            <type>jar</type>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.1</version>
            <type>jar</type>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-validator</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-validator</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.4</version>
            <type>jar</type>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>oro</groupId>
            <artifactId>oro</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.8</version>
            <type>jar</type>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.code.facebookapi</groupId>
            <artifactId>facebook-java-api</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.2</version>
            <type>jar</type>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.code.facebookapi</groupId>
            <artifactId>facebook-java-api-annotation-processor</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.2</version>
            <type>jar</type>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.code.facebookapi</groupId>
            <artifactId>facebook-java-api-schema</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.2</version>
            <type>jar</type>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
            <version>1.4.2</version>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency> 
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>jcl104-over-slf4j</artifactId>
            <version>1.4.2</version>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>        
    </dependencies>
</project>
```

This is the pom.xml and the commons-digester needs xml-apis-1.0b2 which contains org.w3c.dom. I think this is a dependency problem.

Answer (score 142, accepted):

You need to go to Properties for the project in eclipse. Then select "Java Build Path" and tab "Order and Export". Here you can arrange the order of dependencies. Ensure that your JRE is higher up then Maven Dependencies.

Comment: This may be the solution to many things Eclipse and Maven cook up. Thanks a lot.

Comment: This worked for me as a quick fix, although the getNodeValue() solution might be better.

Comment: Perfect. Worked for me

Comment: Excellent. Worked for me as well.

Comment: Thanks for sharing with us. Excellent answer. 100% working. Plus one to u.

Comment: Thanks a ton, almost scratched my head what was going wrong.

Answer (score 18):

Try using:

```
document.getElementsByTagName("name").item(0).getFirstChild().getNodeValue();
```

AFAIK It's "safer" way than `getTextContent()` in some cases.

Comment: this is not really have the same effect. getTextContent(), per the api docs, returns this...

concatenation of the textContent attribute value of every child node, excluding COMMENT_NODE and PROCESSING_INSTRUCTION_NODE nodes. This is the empty string if the node has no children.

Answer (score 9):

I know that is an older post, but for anyone who reached this I had a similar problem and fixed it using the steps indicated in:

http://mergetag.com/the-method-gettextcontent-is-undefined-for-the-type-node/

Namely, `org.w3c.dom.Node.getTextContent() is only available as of Java 1.5` but also note the declarations of `Node`. The `xml-apis-1.0.b2.jar` is the problematic one. Go into the project Properties > Java Build Path > Order and Export tab, and move `xml-apis-1.0.b2.jar` to the top.

Comment: consider writing the solution, because the link/post might get dead.

Comment: Paco: thanks for such a great solution. Keet it up :)

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem, and fixed it by downgrading from Java SDK 1.11 to 1.8